# control RAMPS1.4 in Raspberry Pi5 via Python code (G CODE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi

I made a 3d scanner for my thesis, in this instrument, sensors are moving in each direction with step motors. Those step motors are connected to the RAMPS1.4. when I use my laptop I can control those step motors movement via g code in Python by simply code like this:

```
import serial

myPort = serial.Serial('COM7', 250000, parity='N')

myPort.write('M302 S0\n'.encode())
myPort.write('G1 Z-500 F1000000\n'.encode())
myPort.write('M84\n'.encode())
```

and now, I want to use Raspberry Pi5 to run Python and connect ramps1.4 to that and control step motors in this mini-computer.

when I run this code in the VS app on my Raspberry Pi5, I received a lots of errors. can anyone help me to solve this problem?
NOTE: I'm a beginner in Raspberry Pi programming.

Comment: _"I received a lots of errors"._ What errors? If you are using Raspberry Pi, why are you tagging Arduino? How is it related to Arduino?

Comment: hello dear hcheung. thank you for your attention. maybe I explain badly. I've 5 step motors that are connected to ramps1.4 board and this board is mounted on mega Arduino. now I want to control mega Arduino via g code in Python by Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What errors? error on Raspberry Pi or on Arduino? If you can't debug yourself, do you think others without know the error and your code could magically know how to solve it?

Comment: Most of the errors I receive are in Raspberry Pi and are related to an inability to call Arduino. when I wanted to call that port related to the Arduino in Raspberry Pi like on the laptop (like the codes I wrote in my question) I received an error that said: "could not open COM(port number)". in some of the solutions, I saw was suggested to replace 'COM(port number)' with '/dev/ttyUSB0'. When I tried this, I received the same error again because 'ttyUSB0' doesn't exist in the Pi5 'dev' folder. So,can you guide me to how can I call that port via Python like the codes are written (for a laptop)?

Comment: COM is for Windows system, RPI is a linux box, the port is probably something like `/dev/tty****`, run `dmesg | grep tty` or `ls /dev/tty*` to see what is the port. Also see [this tutorial](https://projects-raspberry.com/read-and-write-from-serial-port-with-raspberry-pi/) on how to config the port.